# HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID is throwing "Object reference error" when instantiated outside of the project

Tags: httpcontext, webapi

I have web application project name say project1 in which i have class Class A. Inside which i have a field
readonly string sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
my sample class looks like this

```
public class A
{
 readonly string sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
--other code;
}
```

Now i am having webapi and referencing the project in the API controller.
i am trying to create an instance of the class A using new keyword
this is throwing the object reference error at line the HTTPContext in the class.

Please let us know how to resolve the dependency on this httpcontext object.

Comment: public override void Init()
        {
            this.PostAuthenticateRequest += MyApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
            base.Init();
        }

        void MyApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
                SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }

Comment: This worked for me doing in Global.asax.cs file